# I deleted all my music, only to have the 4 gb go to ‘other’. Why?

Tags: iphone, icloud

So my phone was really full, I needed more storage. I decided to delete all music, seeing as I never listen to it anyway. So I just deleted the app, and reinstalled it. I had 4 gb of music before deleting it. When deleted, the ‘other’ storage gained 4 gb. This is unacceptable. Can anyone help?

Comment: Did you delete the music or just the app?

Comment: Obviously, just the app - so the songs are all still there, but no longer associated with anything… Did you try rebooting the phone? If so, you might have to do a restore & hope that re-associates.

Comment: He could try using the files app and locating all the MP3 files and manually delete them as well.  I haven't tried it, but it's worth a shot.

Comment: I have an iPhone, so when I deleted the app, the music was also deleted. My 'other' storage is at 17.26 gb, while the 'system' storage is at 6.92 gb. My iPhone only has 32gb. Now with that cleared up, I hope someone can help.